# Pegar pedaço de texto em php

Tags: php

Eu tenho um retorno de um erro qualquer no php, por exemplo.

> QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Eu queria conseguir pegar esse código em especifico, no caso o `1062`, lembrando que o `getCode` do `Exception` ele retornaria o `23000`.

Quero saber como saber se esse trecho em especifico está contido nessa `string`.

Comment: Dependendo da biblioteca que estiver utilizando, o código do erro já vem atribuido a exceção (inner exception) ou ao erro do driver. Qual a biblioteca que está utilizando (PDO, MySQLi, etc...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
$erro = "QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry";
$estaContido = (strpos($erro, "1062") !== false);

var_dump($estaContido); // true
```

Comment: Essa solução sua me atende, valeu brow

Answer (score 2):

Se está utilizando PDO, não há necessidade em realizar o *parse* da `string`. O erro específico já vem "embutido" na `Exception` e no `driver` de conexão.

[PDO - Errors and error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

> PDO standardizes on using SQL-92 SQLSTATE error code strings;
>   individual PDO drivers are responsible for mapping their native codes
>   to the appropriate SQLSTATE codes. The PDO::errorCode() method returns
>   a single SQLSTATE code. **If you need more specific information about an
>   error, PDO also offers an PDO::errorInfo()** method which returns an
>   array containing the SQLSTATE code, the driver specific error code and
>   driver specific error string.

[PDO::errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) ou [PDOException->errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#pdoexception.synopsis)

```
try
{
   /** seu insert **/
}
catch (PDOException $exception)
{
    echo $exception->errorInfo[1];

    //ou

    var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Muito bom Gabriel +1

Comment: Gostei da solução, @Gabriel

Comment: mas não é bem esse 23000 que eu quero pegar, eu queria pegar o 1062

Comment: @gabrielfalieri é importante também saber que o código 23000 é para violação de integridade e 1062 é um dos tipos de violações. O código `var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());` deve lhe trazer uma lista similar a `[0 => "23000" , 1 => 1062 , 2 => "Duplicate entry"]` Valide se está na chave correta.

Comment: @gabrielfalieri https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `preg_match` assim você vai poder pegar **qualquer código erro**, além do erro *1062*, um exemplo supondo que esteja usando `mysqli`:

```
if (!...) { //if que falhou
     $error = $mysqli->error;
     $code = 0;
     if (preg_match('#Q[^\[]+\[\d+\]:[^\d]+(\d+)\s#', $error, $matchs)) {
          $code = $matchs[1]; //Pega o código extraído da string
     } else {
          $code = $mysqli->errno; //Pega o código do QLSTATE se não conseguir obter nada com preg_match
     }
}
```